# ¿Por qué FreeLibrary no me funciona?

Tags: c++, visual-c++

He creado una aplicación en c++ que consigue con éxito listarme las DLL de otra aplicación, sin embargo cuando intento hacer un FreeLibrary de una DLL en concreto simplemente no hace nada, me devuelve FALSE. Estoy Usando Visual c++ 2017

```
BOOL FreeLibrary(
  HMODULE hLibModule
);
```

Comment: ¿ Que te devuelve `GetLastError( )` justo después de tu llamada fallida ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No puedes usar FreeLibrary para sacar una .dll de otra aplicación, Windows no permite esto. Si lo que quieres es terminar con algunos módulos de un programa entonces debes implementar FreeLibrary dentro de la aplicación con la dll a liberar. Es decir, por ejemplo deberías crear una dll que lista los módulo de una aplicación y usa FreeLibrary,  y después inyectar esta dll en la aplicación. Pero "externamente" no puedes.

Comment: Muchas Gracias. Y por qué si me deja listar las DLL?

Comment: Porque eso si lo permite Windows. Pero retirar una dll en muchos aspectos incumpliría una seguridad básica de las aplicaciones en Windows, por su funcionamiento estarías retirando funciones y variables lo que haría que la aplicación diese error y terminara de ejecutarse.